# ModelTest class and pri file

Tags: qt

I'm trying to teach myself model/view construction and [here](http://wiki.qt.io/Model_Test) I found the ModelTest class. They also in this link mention .pri file and that I'm suppose to include it but I just cannot find it anywhere. Could someone tell me what to do about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a spelling mistake. You have to include the `pro` file. The source can be found here:

http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/trees/4.7/tests/auto/modeltest